# PHP Substring between two specific characters

Tags: php

I have the following code which gives me exactly what I first needed (uppercase words after the first `=` in the string `$data`:

```
if (($pos = strpos($data, "=")) !== FALSE) { 
    $whatIWant = ucwords(substr($data, $pos+1)); 
}
```

What I now need to do is exactly the same thing, but ignore anything after (and including) the first `&` in the same string (`$data`).

My PHP is weak, please can someone tell me how to update the above to do this? I haven't been able to find the answer here but if I've missed it please tell me.

**Sample strings:**

> destination=Apartment+TITLIS+Resort+Wohnung+721&hotelid=0123454656
>
> destination=Rental+Apartment+Mendi+Eder+-+Saint-Jean&hotelid=01234
>
> destination=Three-Bedroom+Holiday+Home+in+Olofstrom&hotelid=98

Comment: start with posting your `$data`

Comment: I've added some samples as requested - thanks

Comment: @chris85 They are URLs, I'm using urldecode($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) to get them. I don't know about the exploding yet I'll give that a look

Comment: @chris85 This is the only PHP I've ever done, there is no reason for me not using $_GET['destination'] other than not knowing about it :) if that will work then it seems straightforward

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this query string is coming from the URL that is used to access the page (as it seems from your comment that you are using `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`) then just use the `$_GET` [Superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php):

```
echo ucwords($_GET['destination']);
```

If the query string is coming from somewhere else then there is a tool for that, [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php):

```
parse_str($data, $result);
```

Your first example query string yields:

```
Array
(
    [destination] => Apartment TITLIS Resort Wohnung 721
    [hotelid] => 0123454656
)
```

So then just:

```
echo ucwords($result['destination']);
```

Comment: Thank you - does this also do the upper case function or do I just add ucwords around the $result['destination']?

Comment: It does not change case, if you need title case then yes, `ucwords`.

Comment: Thanks one more question, how do I replace the string value with the URL ($data) that I'm currently getting from urldecode?

Comment: @nathanhayfield: yes but that will parse the URL and give you the query string which OP already has.  Then `parse_str` is still needed.

Answer (score 2):

**Your solution here:** you can check here: https://3v4l.org/ohgvE

```
<?php 
$data = "destination=Apartment+TITLIS+Resort+Wohnung+721&hotelid=0123454656";
if (($pos = strpos($data, "=")) !== FALSE) { 
    $whatIWant = ucwords(substr($data, $pos+1)); 
    $whatIWant = explode("&", $whatIWant); // creating array from string
    $whatIWant = $whatIWant[0]; // before & is first array element
    echo "Ans1: \n";
    echo $whatIWant;
    // Output: Apartment+TITLIS+Resort+Wohnung+721
    // if you want your output with & just add & 
    echo "\n\nAns2: \n";

    $whatIWant = $whatIWant."&";

    echo $whatIWant;
    // now Output iss: 
    // Apartment+TITLIS+Resort+Wohnung+721&
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the [`$_GET`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) superglobal is the proper way to get a `GET` parameter in PHP.

```
$_GET['destination']
```

will have your `destination`, and it will already be url decoded.

> The GET variables are passed through urldecode().